# How to post data in the web api by stored procedure and EF db first approach

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem in posting data in my web API project, I have a action method and a stored procedure and a table by which a want to perform post operation but I am getting internal server error message when i am posting data from fiddler my table structure given below

```
 public partial class tblImage
    {
        public string ImageId { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string ImageCategory { get; set; }
    }
```

my stored procedure code made by Visual studio is given below

```
 public virtual int InsertDynamicImage(string imageId, string imagePath, string imageCategory)
        {
            var imageIdParameter = imageId != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ImageId", imageId) :
                new ObjectParameter("ImageId", typeof(string));

            var imagePathParameter = imagePath != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ImagePath", imagePath) :
                new ObjectParameter("ImagePath", typeof(string));

            var imageCategoryParameter = imageCategory != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ImageCategory", imageCategory) :
                new ObjectParameter("ImageCategory", typeof(string));

            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction("InsertDynamicImage", imageIdParameter, imagePathParameter, imageCategoryParameter);
        }
    }
```

my controller code is given below

```
 [HttpPost]
        [Route("api/tblProducts/DynamicImage")]
        public IHttpActionResult AddDynamic(tblImage Review)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var AltAddress = db.InsertDynamicImage(Review.ImageId, Review.ImagePath, Review.ImageCategory);


            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Review.ImageId }, Review);

        }
```

Error message given by fiddler shown below

```
{
    "Message":"An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage":"UrlHelper.Link must not return null.",
    "ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException",
    "StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Http.Results.CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult`1.Execute()\r\n
at System.Web.Http.Results.CreatedAtRouteNegotiatedContentResult`1.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n
at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Comment: Internal Server Error is a bit vague. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: what you need for details ?,Actually problem is that it is posting the data in my database but it is giving internal server error in the fiddler

Comment: Sounds like something on the return path then. Are you debugging or running against a server? I'd suggest debugging and coming back when you have a more specific error message. Internal Server Error is too broad to diagnose

Comment: I update error message in my question ,please help me

Comment: You're gonna have two kinds of issues.  (1) Did you make it into the ApiContoller (method) WITH a hydrated parameter object?  Put a breakpoint on the first line of you "public IHttpActionResult AddDynamic(tblImage Review)" method, and see if the parameter object is hydrated (not null with properties set).  If its this kind of issue, you have a plumbing issue.  If you get the object on the service side properly hydrated, then you have an issue with your item getting into EF is my guess.  But you need to describe which behavior you have to help others help you.

Comment: i put the break point on first line and it have all value which i passed from the fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try naming your attribute route.

```
[Route("api/tblProducts/DynamicImage", name="GetProductImage")]
```

Then use the route name when calling the link.

If you want to learn more have a look at the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#route-names).

UPDATE
To clarify you need to use the route name within the call to CreatedAtRoute. Like so:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetProductImage", new { id = Review.ImageId }, Review);
```

If that still doesn't work can you post your route config?

Comment: Where did you use the route name exactly? Updated my answer with the exact location to call it.

Comment: No problems, glad it helped. Show your appreciation by accepting as the answer 

Comment: Sir i think your update is working because it returning 201 created and no error in fiddler and thank you sir for your help but sir can you describe what change you done ,how it is working ?

Comment: and sir i want connect with you for future so Is there any option ?